# Python 3.5.1 Unable to import numpy after update

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, anaconda

I'm running Python 3.5.1 on a Windows 7 machine. I've been using Anaconda without issue for several months now. This morning, I updated my packages (conda update --all) and now I can't import numpy (version 1.11.0) or pandas(version 0.18.1).

The error I get from Python is:
Syntax Error: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape. This error occurs when the import statement is executed.

I'm able to import other packages, some from anaconda's bundle and some from other sources without issue.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Comment: You didn't update from python 2 to 3, did you?:)

Comment: Haha sadly no, wish it was something obvious like that. I've been on 3+ since I've started working with Python a few months ago. I'm still relatively new to it... but this is the first time I've had an update break anything. I'm using a 64bit version of anaconda if that helps...

Comment: That error comes just from the `import` statement?

Comment: Can you post the entire traceback, please?

Comment: John - yes it was just by executing the import statement. Michael, unfortunately I can't do that now. I was able to get this resolved (and will answer this question) by removing and reinstalling the packages using conda. Wasn't the ideal solution... but it worked :)

Comment: I did `conda update anaconda` from Anaconda3 4.0.0 to 4.1.0 and get the same issue

Comment: Hey Toasteez - removing and reinstalling the packages via conda resolved the problem for me yesterday. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with prefix replacement and backslashes not being escaped properly.  More details at:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38107818/1170370

Comment: Thanks msarahan - I'll suggest some edits for the other question to make it more searchable.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue using conda to remove and reinstall the packages that were failing to import. I will leave the question marked unanswered to see if anyone else has a better solution, or guidance on how to prevent this in the future.