# Import numpy throws error: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \uXXXX escape

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, unicode, utf-8, unicode-escapes

I have installed `pyzo` and `miniconda` under Windows 10 and installed `numpy` and `matplotlib` using `conda install`. But when I'm trying to run

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<tmp 1>", line 3, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "c:\users\jakub\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 165, in <module>
    from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config
  File "c:\users\jakub\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__config__.py", line 5
    lapack_mkl_info={'libraries': ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll'], 'define_macros': [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)], 'include_dirs': ['c:\users\jakub\miniconda3\\Library\\include'], 'library_dirs': ['c:\users\jakub\miniconda3\\Library\\lib']}
                                                                                                                                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

I do not have any non-standard character either in my code nor in the directory structure...I have read many posts referring to similar problems with UTF-8 but this is different as it happens during the initial import.

Comment: Check if your installation is complete and working, see for instance [this very recent post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38083176/python-3-5-1-unable-to-import-numpy-after-update#38083176). Reinstalling packages might help.

Comment: @QoP: Use code formatting for tracebacks, not quote formatting.

Comment: Tried to conda uninstall numpy and then install it back but the problem still persists... Some modules can import some cannot...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When conda installs packages, it replaces the prefix, to make things relocatable.  Unfortunately, it does not intelligently escape backslashes, so on Windows, these unescaped backslashes lead to the error you see.

In recent versions of conda, we use forward slashes in prefix replacement, and this issue goes away.  If you can update conda, go do that.  If not, numpy has prefixes in the following files:

```
"Lib/site-packages/numpy/distutils/site.cfg"
"Scripts/f2py.py"
"Lib/site-packages/numpy/config.py"
"Lib/site-packages/numpy/distutils/config.py"
```

check the latter 3 especially, and replace any non-escaped backslashes ( \ ) with either escaped ones ( \\ ) or forward slashes

Answer (score 3):

So, for people having trouble in

```
import numpy
```

using Windows 10 + Anaconda:

I replaced all single '\' to double '\\' in

```
\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__config__.py
```

I could import numpy after that.

Comment: So, the lesson learnt is this: If you get  Unicode syntax error in Python 3, look in your source code if there are any backward slash characters ('\'). If there are none, look into the libraries. They may contain the offending character. Once found, replace them with forward slash or double backward slash.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked for me: double `\` before and after users word.

For example: `\\users\\admin\anaconda3\sample.wav`

I am using python 3.6 on Windows 7

Not sure why the post keeps only one \ after and before users word in the path

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
sys.path.append('K:\Udemy\PYTHON\college')
```

This happened to me while importing the sys path. Try replacing all single '\' with '\\'. Hopefully, you can import after that.

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
sys.path.append('K:\\Udemy\PYTHON\\college')
```

Comment: This doesn’t look like a new answer to me.